# How to add JSON-LD breadcrumbs schema to my website navigation for SEO purposes

Tags: html, seo, schema, breadcrumbs, json-ld

Edit: My understanding of the issue improved as I was writing the question, but I still haven't cleared everything out, that's why I am still asking:

I got introduced to breadcrumbs today and I am still not quite sure I understand them correctly (and I would be really thankful to anyone that helps me understand this better).

I am interested in the SEO part of breadcrumbs: I don't want them displayed anywhere on my website. So I don't want something looking like this:

```
home > products > kids > pants
```

I already have a normal menu (example):

```
_________________________________________________________________________________________________

   LOGO                     About us      Services      Products     Contact us
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And each link on the above menu has sublinks. I only care that the SEO part of the breadcrumbs gets implemented in the already existing (above) menu. Am I making sense?

If so, then how exactly should I implement it? 
I actually tried to follow the example at the bottom of this page: https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList  -- the JASON-LD one. But they have a simple example as follows:

The HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/dresses">Dresses</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/dresses/real">Real Dresses</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/dresses",
    "name": "Dresses"
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real",
     "name": "Real Dresses"
   }
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

As I understand, the above only covers one 'path' in the hierarchy, which probably means I need to recreate the code for all possible paths? I tried to do that for a more complex made-up menu just to put it in this question:

The HTML (mine):

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <div class="logo"><a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/">Have a Biscuit, Potter</a></div>
    <!--not a real website -->
    <div class="menu-links">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us" class="droptitle">About Us</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us/our-journey">Our Journey</a>
                <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us/part-in-fandom">Our Part in the Fandom</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion" class="droptitle">Discussion</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion/harry-needs-biscuit">Why Harry Needs a Biscuit</a>
                <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion/dumbledoor-still-good">Dumbledoor is still good: an Introduction</a>
                <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion/luna-lovegood-revenclaw">Luna Lovegood: Always a Revenclaw</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/contact-us" class="droptitle">Contact Us</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The JSON-LD (mine) - this covers just like 3 links from the above menu. I am not even sure if this is remotely correct but here we go:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org", //or should I change this to https://haveabiscuit-potter.com -?
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
               "itemListElement": [{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com",
                    "name": "Home"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us",
                    "name": "About Us"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us/our-journey",
                    "name": "Our Journey"
                }
            }
        ],
        "itemListElement": [{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com",
                    "name": "Home"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us",
                    "name": "About Us"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/about-us/part-in-fandom",
                    "name": "Our Part in the Fandom"
                }
            }
        ],
        "itemListElement": [{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com",
                    "name": "Home"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion",
                    "name": "Discussion"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.haveabiscuit-potter.com/discussion/dumbledoor-still-good",
                    "name": "Dumbledoor is Still Good"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

</script>
```

//Is the above correct?

Now we get to the part where my understanding improved: seeing that it is tiresome to write the code manually for each link, I googled "JSON-LD breadcrumb generator" - and I found one that makes things easier: https://technicalseo.com/tools/schema-markup-generator/

However, I again get only one path in between the `<script>` tags. So is that how I should generate it? Will the output be hundreds of `<script>` elements each covering only one path? Or can I put them together like what I did above? And in either case, should I insert the enormous JSON-LD code to the footer of every page on my website?

Really thankful that you have read this far, and I really appreciate any help.

Comment: As I added the tags, I got a notice that SEO is offtopic unless I am asking for something related to programming. I guess my question is related to programming and code -- JSON-LD is some kind of code after all. That's why I thought I could ask.

Comment: @Rob A question about JSON-LD syntax is on-topic. Asking how to use JSON-LD to improve SEO (or which syntax Google prefers) would be off-topic

Comment: Google considers it rich snippet abuse to provide markup that doesn't appear to users on your site.  If you implement breadcrumbs without showing them on your site you are risking a penalty from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question: the confusion lied in that I didn't know where to 'put' those breadcrumbs. I thought they were related to the navigation, and that's why they should be present on all pages.

That is not correct, breadcrumbs are unique for each page (well I guess that's obvious but it didn't click for me at first).

Here is the code that made me realize it: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=jsonld&utm_source=breadcrumb

So each page should have the breadcrumb JSON-LD code that is relevant to itself and to its position in the hierarchy of the website. That's it. Now I am off to see how to bulk generate those breadcrumbs for all my website pages.

---

Edit: don't try to add SEO breadcrumb markup if you don't actually have visual breadcrumbs on your pages. Google will penalize you if you attempt to do it. (For more info, read comments below the original question + below this answer).

Comment: Since I am here again: I didn't end up adding those breadcrumbs. Because I don't have 'visual breadcrumbs' on my site in the first place. I tried asking on several forums if adding code breadcrumbs makes sense (SEO wise) when I don't have them visually. I didn't get a definitive response, but I am guessing it does not make sense. So no breadcrumbs for my site.

Comment: Ghadir, is this still your opinion as of today? I've got the same problem, and the client wants JSON-LD breadcrumbs but no visible breadcrumbs

Comment: Yes, it still is my opinion. I had the same issue: the client wanted me to add all possible SEO tweaks, and I jumped straight into whatever SEO schema options I found in Google SEO documentation pages. Breadcrumbs are supposed to exist visually on the page (and after that we might want to tell google: "notice my breadcrumbs!" by using JSON-LD). But it makes no sense to try and tell google to notice breadcrumbs when they don't exist in the first place.

Further reading:

https://yoast.com/breadcrumbs-seo/#:~:text=A%20breadcrumb%20is%20a%20small,for%20SEO%3A%20the%20ultimate%20guide.

Comment: This is me again: also notice the third comment on my original question above - someone said that Google might actually penalize you if you are trying to add markup for something that doesn't actually appear to users on the website. So it's not only useless, it might cause a penalty.

Comment: Yes, I know that rule, it keeps biting me. However, how does Google know something in the HTML is actually a breadcrumb (the user visible part)? There's no HTML tag for it, it might be anything, a span, a p, a div...

Comment: I think they are quite advanced with these stuff, I imagine they can do a visual analysis of the page and compare it that what is expected, they don't just look at the code

Comment: No idea how this would be possible. I've seen some pages recently that have a (visible) breadcrumb hidden away in the footer of the page, in minuscule characters. I suppose the web designer thought this would be a compromise to make Google happy and not bother the client. In my case the "breadcrumb" happens to be contained in some visible text on the page, so I suppose it's all right

Comment: This is an old question and generating breadcrumbs well is still a crumbly affair to say the least. Other than then UI/UX you are bread crumbs serve two very vital funtional benefits a) SEO b) lets admit it in 2024 and on going crawlers are and not going to draw interpretation from every nuke and corner of your and page then make it fit in its own deliverables to end users, you have to hand it over to them on silver platter hence json+Ld. Why would you be penalized if the page as an entry point has not user operable exit point and you add Json+LD e.g. in some cases landing pages for ads.

Comment: adding on to above comment, normal tendency is footers usually have set of exit points connecting to other pages. Suppose you dont have any set of links in footer e.g. pure landing page and have breadcrumb Json. Its misleading as you would want google to follow the hierarchy yet won't have the same for end user. Call it what ever thats playing too much with the game. Have at least some king of exit points e.g. to up one level you don;t necessarily need to follow bread crumb items each one of them but your page should be exiting onto at least one of those points else you will human review.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to see no body cares about this question, but I do. Recently, I added the breadcrumb using bootstrap 5 to my website, since the feeling to make it better striked me somehow. In the beginning, I thought the bot might be smart enough to recognize the "visaul" breadcrumb in HTML, so I go with html implementation first. However, the [google rich result test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) failed to identify my breadcrumb. That's when I realized that only three structured data format are accepted by google: [reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/intro-structured-data#format-placement).

Wish your website a prosperous one!

Comment: I asked this long ago and I can see now that I was really not knowledgeable about what I was asking. In order to add the breadcrumb SEO code, one should have breadcrumbs in the first place. My website didn't, and I just thought I could add the code without actually having breadcrumbs. Mistakes one does as a beginner in the field.